# Name binding in `except` clause deleted after the clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

How can I stop Python from deleting a name binding, when that name is
used for binding the exception that is caught? When did this change in
behaviour come into Python?

I am writing code to run on both Python 2 and Python 3:

```python
exc = None
try:
    1/0
    text_template = "All fine!"
except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
    text_template = "Got exception: {exc.__class__.__name__}"

print(text_template.format(exc=exc))
```

Notice that `exc` is explicitly bound *before* the exception handling, so Python knows it is a name in the outer scope.

On Python 2.7, this runs fine and the `exc` name survives to be used in
the `format` call::

```
Got exception: ZeroDivisionError
```

Great, this is exactly what I want: The `except` clause binds the name
and I can use that name in the rest of the function to refer to the
exception object.

On Python 3.5, the `format` call fails because apparently the `exc`
binding is *deleted*::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
NameError: name 'exc' is not defined
```

Why is the `exc` binding deleted from the outer scope? How are we meant
to reliably preserve the name binding to use it *after* the `except`
clause?

When did this change come into Python, where is it documented?

Would I be right to report this as a bug in Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not a bug. The behavior you are experiencing is clearly and explicitly defined in the [Python 3 documentation for the `try`/`except` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement). The reason for this behavior is also given:

> When an exception has been assigned using `as target`, it is cleared at the end of the `except` clause. This is as if
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>    foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     try:
>         foo
>     finally:
>         del N
> ```
>
> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be able to refer to it after the `except` clause. **Exceptions are cleared because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive until the next garbage collection occurs**.

The reason declaring the name outside of the scope of the `try`/`except` block didn't work is because you used `exc` in the `as` clause. So that was the name Python deleted.

The fix is to use a different name in the `as` clause to bind the exception to, and then assign the global variable to the different exception name:

```
>>> exc_global = None
>>> try:
    1 / 0
    text_template = "All fine!"
except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
    exc_global = exc
    text_template = "Got exception: {exc.__class__.__name__}"


>>> print(text_template.format(exc=exc_global))
Got exception: ZeroDivisionError
```

As Anthony Sottile noted in the comments, the disassembly for the `try`/`except` code also clearly supports the above statements made by the documentation:

```
>>> code = """
try:
    1/0
    text_template = "All fine!"
except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
    text_template = "Got exception: {exc.__class__.__name__}"
"""
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(code)
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            16 (to 18)

  3           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
              8 POP_TOP

  4          10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('All fine!')
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (text_template)
             14 POP_BLOCK
             16 JUMP_FORWARD            38 (to 56)

  5     >>   18 DUP_TOP
             20 LOAD_NAME                1 (ZeroDivisionError)
             22 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       54
             26 POP_TOP
             28 STORE_NAME               2 (exc)
             30 POP_TOP
             32 SETUP_FINALLY           10 (to 44)

  6          34 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Got exception: {exc.__class__.__name__}')
             36 STORE_NAME               0 (text_template)
             38 POP_BLOCK
             40 POP_EXCEPT
             42 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
        >>   44 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             46 STORE_NAME               2 (exc)
             48 DELETE_NAME              2 (exc)
             50 END_FINALLY
             52 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 56)
        >>   54 END_FINALLY
        >>   56 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             58 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: The disassembly of this is pretty clear too (throw it in a function, run `dis.dis(f)`) -- it adds essentially `exc = None; del exc` to the end of the `finally` block

Comment: @AnthonySottile Great point. I'll add that to my answer.