# namespace scope for variables inside try block

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, scope

Regarding these two options:

```
try:
    userid = get_userid()
except:
    userid = ""
```

vs.

```
userid = ""
try:
    userid = get_userid()
except:
    pass
```

Is there any difference, specifically wondering how the namespace would work out if `userid` is only set within the `try` block? Do they both have the same namespace scope?

Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: **try** is not a new scoping block.  The scope of the variable is from first appearance to the end of the function, class, ...

Comment: `except:
    pass` shouldn't be preferred

Comment: There is an interesting question that someone has marked as a duplicate of this. Should it be closed on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292479/name-binding-in-except-clause-deleted-after-the-clause

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't think so. That Q+A is specifically about the catched exception in the except block and only in python-3.x.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Nah, nah. There's a slight difference between the questions. The dupe I linked to was asking why declaring a global name, and then using the name in `except as <name>` was raising a `NameErrror` when the name was later used. There're definitely related, but not exact dupes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blocks like `try` and `except` (but also `if`, `elif`, `else`, `with`) have no "local scope". However you can't and shouldn't expect that any code in the `try` block will be executed (because it could fail and go directly in the `except` or `finally` block).

But are you sure that `""` as "failing" `user_id` makes sense? Why not something else, for example `None`?

Also you should avoid catching all exceptions, so I would prefer something like this:

```
try:
    userid = get_userid()
except Exception:  # or a more specific exception
    userid = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locals()` to see the defined variables in each case. There is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the resulting state after execution of the two statements you gave.

If you omit the `userid=""` in the second, the variable will result undefined if an error occurs.

The first statement should be preferred since it is (a) nicer and (b) faster (`userid` gets a value assigned twice if no error occurs).